# Error re-adding a user to Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: azure-devops

Can't add a user who was previously linked to a project, then I removed it and now I'm trying to add him again, getting the following error :

> "Could not add user Microsoft.TeamFoundation.BindPendingIdentity;upn:92a19a0b-ae59-4d7c-b7ae-be71ce46bd82\xxxxxx@hotmail.com in tenant 92a19a0b-ae59-4d7c-b7ae-be71ce46bd82 to group Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1551374245-781684931-2852341834-2908411269-2087932524-1-2951360343-342954306-2166683068-3335447427 in account da851b74-db4a-42d3-b619-962e5b1a61b2 in tenant 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
>   Session Id: 2c95c6b8-0dfe-415f-962c-3eafbb0a5a7e

Details:

[image: 1. Error]
[image: 2. Error]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is not a programming question.

Comment: @leppie It's about a tool used by developers. There are literally thousands of questions about TFS/VS Team Services on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DanielMann: There is another SE site for that.

Comment: @leppie From http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…

a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
**software tools commonly used by programmers**; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: Oh well, I thought http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is the place to do it, but I guess SO is not just code anymore...

Comment: Hi guys, I 'm asking the question in the wrong place?

Comment: It seems that it is indeed a bug, they say it will fixed:
[Link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2808031/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry that you are still having this issue. In looking at this issue, we need additional information and it would be great if you can open a support ticket.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/cloud-services-assisted-support-vs

The support team will be able to collect additional data as needed to help you with this issue.

Thanks
Shantaram